# svn rebasing and history lost

Tags: svn, history, rebase

We currently have 2 branches:

```
/repo/branch/current_version
/repo/branch/next_version
```

**current_version** is a branch where all developers currently works.

We starting a next version and created **next_version** branch from some point in current_version, while work on current_version is still continuing. In next_version we do some development and in next months the branch will become our main one, where all development will be done.

Since there's development on current_branch, we thought periodically (say once per 2 weeks) to rebase next_version. This in order to keep both branch in sync, so when all developers will eventually drop current_branch and move to next_release, next_release will contain all current_branch's feature integrated and tested.

The problem is rebasing. Actually rebasing is merging latest commits of current_branch to next_version. So if I'll examine history of commited files in next_release, all I'll see is the merge commits and not the history (commits/authors/annotation) of current_version.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you haven't missed anything. This is a big problem with using SVN for version control.

I ran into it over and over again at my last job. Every time somebody committed something to current_branch (to stick with your terminology), the commit message would have to be copied manually so it could be used in the merge commit message. This quickly became a huge pain.

That's why new version control software has come out with better merging capabilities (Git, Mercurial, and Bazaar come to mind).

---

**EDIT:** Apparently SVN has fixed this issue. SVN 1.5 and up incorporate [merge-sensitive logs and annotations](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.logblame). Use the flag --use-merge-history (-g) with svn merge and svn blame to see the commit messages from the merged branch.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot your deleted comment about svn 1.6 feature "Merge-Sensitive Logs and Annotationscomment" is what I'm looking for. Using flag -use-merge-history(-g) along with svn log/blame will do the work. I see the feature present in 1.5 too. Update your answer and I'll accept it :)